# How do I add weights to a mesh (to be used for a particle system) corresponding to an image?

Tags: particles, weight-painting

It is difficult to recreate weights that exactly look like the image I have.
[image]

This picture shows what I currently have. I want to add a particle system using weights.
[image]
The black values should correspond to red while the white values to blue.
I'm a beginner to Blender, so don't go about showing advanced stuff without adequate explanations.

Any ideas as to how I could go about doing this?

Comment: have you subdivided your mesh enough?

Comment: I can, but I can't exactly recreate the picture. That's the problem.